# Simulate web browser user input programatically c++

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

How do i send a JavaScript command to a web browser from an external c++ application?

At the moment what i am currently doing is saving the HTML file locally, modifying it, and send a command to refresh the browser from my application.

This might be trivial for some, but I was wondering if i can send the JavaScript command directly to the web browser and see the changes happen without modifying the source code.

I am currently using the following: Firefox, Chrome and IE.

I tried with modify files from within my application using QWebEngineView but it takes a ridiculously long time to load the pages and some webpages are complaining that the browser is too old.

Comment: search for "headless chrome", you can then use a RPC style communication between your app and the browser that will run without a GUI and send javascript commands.

Comment: Cool! I will try it, looking at the documentation it seems it can do what i need.